# Should I exclude dummy variable created from independent variable in multivariate regression model?

Tags: regression, interaction, categorical-encoding

I have the following model:

$ \ln(wage) = \beta_0 + \beta_1educ + \beta_2educ*college $

the variable $college$ is from the condition that if $educ \geq 16$.

Should I include the variable $college$ in the model or just omit it as it is already explained by the $educ$ variable?

I built the model from the following question:

run a regression which allows impact of educ on wage
to be different between those who have and don't have a college degree.

1. what is the estimated impact of educ on wage for non-college graduates?
2. what is the estimated impact of educ on wage for college graduates?
3. Is there an evidence that the impacts for the two groups are different?

Comment: By including that interaction, you are saying that the impact of an additional year of education is different when that extra year is postgraduate education than when that extra year is undergraduate (or earlier) education, which I find reasonable. Perhaps it would be worth saying why you wanted to include that $educ * college$ variable in the first place, however. Is it because you wanted to allow for a nonlinear effect of education on the $\log(\text{wage})?$ // Is $educ\ge 16$ a great measure of holding a bachelor's degree? Plenty of people graduate earlier/later...but they do graduate!

Comment: Yes, I think that the impact is different when the extra year is postgraduate. I use $educ \geq 16$ because my professor told me to use it. But I think the main question here is that should I omitted the dummy variable if it is from the variable that is already in the model?

Comment: You do not already have the $educ\ge 16$ indicator variable in the model. You have a related variable in the model by having $educ$ on its own, yes, but the $educ\ge 16$ indicator variable is distinct from $educ$ on its own. Put differently, would you leave out an $x^2$ term just because you already have an $x$ term in the model? Why or why not?

Comment: I think I won't. The relationship is not linear. But in this case, however, I think I should exclude it is not possible to have $college = 1$ if $educ$ is lower than $16$. The part below $16$ is irrelevant for college grad and I think I would be harder to interpret in intercept term.